# Why am I getting a IllegalArgumentException in my Android App?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app, and I am getting the most annoying NFE for, what seems like, no reason.

So, here is what I have in my app:

```
int amount = 7;
NumberFormat myNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
TextView money = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.money_view);
money.setText(myNumberFormat.format(amount));
```

And for some reason, I am getting a NFE when I try to get the NumberFormat currency instance. As a test, to make sure I wasn't going crazy, I also wrote this stand-alone:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class NFETest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int amount = 7;
        NumberFormat myNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        System.out.println(myNumberFormat.format(amount));
    }
}
```

The stand-alone works with no problems. So, what gives ... why am I getting this error?

**EDIT:**

Looking further down LogCat, it looks like it is an IllegalArgumentException instead of a NFE. However, this doesn't make it any less strange. I have "Locale.US" set, so that shouldn't make any difference. However, some quick googling says it may be my tablet thinking it is not in the US. It may be a hardware issue, and not software after all.

Comment: Did you tried using String.valueOf(myNumberFormat.format(amount)) in setText?

Comment: @Shivam I just tried "String.valueOf" and got the same error.

Comment: @PPartisan a double gives me the same error.

Comment: Could you post your `LogCat` exception please Brian? On the face of it your code looks fine to me, so it may give some more clues.

Comment: @PPartisan I would, but it is on a different machine. As it turns out, further down the stack trace, LogCat is saying "IllegalArgumentException" on the line as opposed to NFE.

Comment: Did you set your layout in your activity's onCreate(): setContentView(R.layout.your_layout), and does that specific layout contain the money_view TextView?

Comment: @mjp66 I did, and it does.

Comment: Out of curiosity, then, would you mind posting your entire activity and layout file? It's strange that you get the desired result showing up in your Log output but chokes on setText()... it suggests that this can't just be down to hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Just use wrappers(Integer, Float, Double, BigDecimal or others):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer amount = 7;
    NumberFormat myNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    System.out.println(myNumberFormat.format(amount));

    int amount2 = 11;
    System.out.println(myNumberFormat.format(Integer.valueOf(amount2)));
}
```

In other solution, you may use `Integer.valueOf(..)` Look like here: http://ideone.com/0ZKsS3
But your example works too. Look at online compiler: http://ideone.com/0ZKsS3

Comment: Apparently I can use a primitive type, because it works in the little stand-alone class.

Comment: @Brian It's strange. Because your example works on my machine, and works via online compiler. Please, post your  the full stack trace. If I faced with this problem, my the first solution would be use wrappers.

Comment: After looking around the LogCat, It appears it is an IllegalArgumentException, which is just as strange. After some quick googling, it looks like it may have to do with where my tablet believes it is located. Even though I chose "Locale.US" this may be the issue. Not sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
int amount = 7;
NumberFormat myNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
TextView money = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.money_view);
money.setText(String.valueOf(myNumberFormat.format(amount)));
```

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried "Integer.valueOf" as was also suggested.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary - `format()` returns a `String` value. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(long)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  int amount = 7;
  NumberFormat myNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
  TextView money = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.money_view);
  money.setText(String.valueOf(myNumberFormat.format(amount)));// your error is here.
    //go on as normal
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //handle error
}
```

you should catch the exception and handle the parse error accordingly.

**Or you should try for different values :**

```
    double num = 1323.526;

    NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    System.out.println("US: " + defaultFormat.format(num));

    Locale swedish = new Locale("sv", "SE");
    NumberFormat swedishFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(swedish);
    System.out.println("Swedish: " + swedishFormat.format(num));
```

**OUTPUT :**

> US: $1,323.53
>
> Swedish: 1 323,53 kr

Hope this time it will help you to catch your problem.

Comment: Please see my EDIT. It looks like it may be an issue with my hardware.

Comment: can you please post you logcat /

Comment: I cannot ... it is on a different machine that does not have any network connectivity.

Comment: Log.e("value" , ""+(myNumberFormat.format(amount)); What you get please check

Comment: It is $7.00 ... just like it should be. I'm really beginning to believe that it is a hardware issue.

Comment: Then my friend the problem is with textview.